# How does continue work in this code? (python)

Tags: python, loops, continue

```
# pede pelo nome do aluno, ou termina o programa, se "fim".
while(True):
    aluno = input("\nInsira o nome do aluno: ")
    while(aluno == "" or aluno == None):
        aluno = input("Por favor insira o nome do aluno: ")
    if (aluno == "Fim" or aluno == "fim"):
        print(bold + "Fechando o programa...\n" + bold_end) 
        sys.exit()  
    if (aluno.istitle() != True):
        qst = input("\nEste não parece ser um nome regular. Tem certeza que deseja prosseguir?")
        if (qst == 'N' or qst == 'No' or qst== 'Não' or qst == "n" ):
            continue
```

This is a little snippet of a program I've made to help me correcting the tests of my students. He does exactly what I want, but the last four lines that I've exposed work, and I don't know why.

If a name that is not composed not only of uppercase and lowercase letters is inserted, the program must question if I want to proceed with that name. If I type "N" or anything of the like, the program restarts, and asks me again for the name of the student. If I type in any other thing, the program proceeds as it should. The question is: why?

Comment: do you have anything inside `while(True)` below `continue` ?

Comment: @furas yes I do. The code keeps on asking the user for the number of correct answers. What I wanted is for, after negating, the code would go back to the start of the while loop, and if I said yes, that It would keep on going. It does exactly that, but I've kinda done it by accident.

Comment: Don't use `<expression> != True`. Use `not <expression>` instead.

Comment: if you answert `N` then `continue` returns to `while(True)` - if you answer something different then it doesn't execute `continue` and it executes next lines of code which are inside `while(True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have mixed up `continue` and `break`.

`break` ends a loop. `continue` starts the next iteration (*continues* the loop from the top).

Comment: Thanks. So I guess that to do what I want properly I should create a second loop, right?

Comment: I'd say you want to study http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response closely.

Comment: that did it! Thank you